# Convert an upgraded SVN repo from linear to sharded?

Tags: svn, fsfs

I had an SVN 1.4 repo with filesystem format 2. I moved it to a new server using hotcopy (couldn't dump/load due to many checksum errors in old revisions). After upgrade, "svnadmin info" gives the following:

> Repository Format: 5
>
> Compatible With Version: 1.10.0
>
> Repository Capability: mergeinfo
>
> Filesystem Type: fsfs
>
> Filesystem Format: 8
>
> FSFS Sharded: no
>
> FSFS Logical Addressing: no

After doing this, I learned about "svnadmin pack", but could not run it because as you can see the repo is not sharded. And it appears that now that I've upgraded the repo, "fsfs-reshard.py" won't work anymore either.

Is there any way to convert this repository to a sharded format so I can pack it? Or did I need to convert to sharded prior to upgrading?

Answer (score 0):

I think the way which defentily will work is a `svnadmin dump` and `svnadmin load` like stated here: [svn dumpload faq](http://subversion.apache.org/faq.html#dumpload)

You could try [svn fsfs reshard](https://github.com/ymartin59/svn-fsfs-reshard)

> This Subversion FSFS shard administration tool allows to know how a repository FSFS is organized (linear or sharded layout, logical or physical addressing) and tune shard size for better performance.

It may be use to migrate an upgraded repository from linear to sharded layout, but still with physical addressing.